# Connection pooling for an Android app which connects to a Postgresql DB

Tags: android, python, postgresql, connection-pooling

I want to have some kind of failsafe in place for my Android social-network-style app so that when a lot of users are connected through the app's web service / business logic mid-layer to my Postgresql database, it continues to function and to handle a large number of concurrent connections.

I don't know how many users to expect at maximum load but about 70 users at any given time would be nice.

What would be the best way to achieve this through code/infrastructure?

I already plan to use a small web service to handle the database connections, but I'm not sure how I would handle the connection pooling in any platform I end up using, whether its PHP, Python or Ruby.

Also, how many users can a typical un-optimized instance (on a Ubuntu Linux 14.04 machine with 4GB RAM) of PostgreSQL handle at a single time?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize, I've never had to delete a post before. Is there an undo?

Comment: Thanks, looks like you found the old copy (the one you deleted) and restored it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23701875/398670 . Readers of this question are advised to take a look there for context - in particular for clarification of what the intent of this one is. (I'm removing my now-irrelevant comments).

Comment: Amended my original answer to clarify.